# Yii2 sort by with calculations in an ActiveDataProviderRecord

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-active-records

I would like to add a groupby with cacluations in yii2 ActiveDataProvider.
SO currently i have the following fields in my database

```
tbl_products
   id, products, pts_log,pts_chum
```

SO i would like to group my data with the formula

```
pts_log * pts_chum / 100
```

So i have the following in my controller

```
ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['(pts_log * pts_chum / 100)' => SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => $this->paginator['perPage']/2,
            'page' => $this->paginator['page']
        ],
    ]);
```

But am now getting an error

```
undefined (pts_log * pts_chum / 100)
```

This works with one item key like `pts_log`. What do i add to make sorting work with a formulae.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an alias to the field the query is to be grouped by and use the alias in sort.

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select ('count(*) as c, ((pts_log * pts_chum / 100) as calc_field')
    ->from('tbl_products')
    ->groupBy('calc_field');
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['calc_field' => SORT_DESC]],
]);
```

Use simple the desired aggregates instead of *count(*)*.

Answer (score 0):

In this case You getting an error **undefined (pts_log * pts_chum / 100)** because it is not column name and not valid expression.

You need create new variable in ActiveRecord model and and fill it with data from the calculated expression.

Then this variable name use in sort `'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['expr_item' => SORT_DESC]]`
Look to http://webtips.krajee.com/filter-sort-summary-data-gridview-yii-2-0/ A similar option is considered here.

Or prepare $query like:

```
$tn = TblProdukts::tableName();
$query = TblProdukts::find()->select([
                        TblProdukts::tableName().'.*',
                        "(".$tn.".id*".$tn.".rank/100) AS expr"
                    ]);
```

In Active Record class create variable `$expr`;

If needed add it to safe rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[  
                'expr'// expression
            ], 
                'safe'],
        ];
    }
```